# Using "shall" in Contracted Conditionals

Tags: grammaticality

Can I use "shall" to imply conditionality in the following way:

"Shall he be killed, his inheritance will be bequeathed to his sons."

I guess I could use the following sentence, though I am not sure:

"Should he be killed, his inheritance will be bequeathed to his sons."

Comment: https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/plain_language/articles/mandatory/ What's the only word that means mandatory? Here's what law and policy say about "shall, will, may and must." -- Slightly more general information, but perhaps helpful for future reference and to lend some perspective to the problem.

Comment: @Bread The discussion in the paper pertains to what the law mandates, the legal consequence. By contrast, this question here is concerned with the *conditions* that must be fulfilled for the law to be applicable. It is highly unusual to use *shall* in the condition.

Answer (score 3):

You're right about "**should**".

[AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=should) says:

> 3. Used to express conditionality or contingency: If she should fall, then so would I.

So does [Meriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/should):

> past tense of shall
>   1 —used in auxiliary function to express condition
>   if he should leave his father, his father would die —Genesis 44:22 (Revised Standard Version)

---

Regarding the use of "**shall**", [Webster's New World College Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/shall#websters?direct_search_result=yes) says:

> shall
>   auxiliary verb
>   ...
>   used in formal conditional subordinate clauses: if any man shall hear, let him remember

*However*, I've *never seen "shall" used in an inversion without "if"* as in your first suggested example. ***Not*** in a **single** contract.

In contrast, I've encountered constructs such as "`Should the Vendor fail to ...`" in tons of contracts.

Comment: I may not phrase this right, but... I think _should_ is needed because you're setting out the (definite) consequences _once something has already happened_ (the vendor _has failed_; "he" _has been killed_ etc.). By contrast, "_if any man shall hear, let him remember_" is more of a hypothetical? / aspirational? thing... _if_ someone hears, you _want_ them to remember: you're not setting in stone that either they _will_ remember, nor, really, _contracting_ them to remember.